# Allowing only one alpha character - RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I am trying  to only allow one single character suing regex but it seems that it is allowing multiple amounts through.

I have tried this..

```
$char = trim($_REQUEST['char']);

/* Validate char */

if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z]{1}/', $char)) {
    $char = 'a';
}

echo $char;
```

and this..

```
$char = trim($_REQUEST['char']);

/* Validate char */

if (!preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]{1}/', $char)) {
    $char = 'a';
}

echo $char;
```

But neither work. They always output the result even if `$_REQUEST['char']` is equal to `aa`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're matching one character, but you aren't matching **only** one character. Any string with at least one alpha character will pass your current regex.

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]$/', $char)) {
    $char = 'a';
}
```

The `^` indicates the start of the string, and the `$` indicates the end. No need for the `{1}` in this case.

You could alternatively check `strlen($char) == 1` in the `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried it like that with the first example I gave above but it didn't work, will try it with the second.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. You need to use ^ to match beginning and $ to match end of string you are trying to match.

```
<?
$char = "aa";
/* Validate char */
if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]$/', $char)) {
   echo "found only ONE char";
} else {
echo "one single char not found"
}
?>
```